Existence of "Petrie polyhedron" in 16-cell.
I am looking for a $2d$ closed simplicial subcomplex within the 16-cell (4-orthoplex) seperating two opposite cells in a "balanced" way - similar as how the Petrie polygon seperates two opposite faces in an octahedron (3-orthoplex). I am pretty sure there is no such spherical subcomplex, but maybe a Klein bottle? On the other hand, it is then not clear then what 'separating' means.. I am happy for any thoughts on this.
If there is some systematic reason why this can't exist, I am also happy to know.

The subcomplex including all faces except for the faces of these two opposite cells satisfies the desired conditions (it is of course not a surface though).

This is not an answer to the question.

This is of course an answer. Still, I removed the question mark which apparently triggered the erroneous "This is not an answer" reaction.

As my question was very broad (sorry for that), this is a totally valid answer. I think the fact that there is nothing better has something to do with the fact that $16 = 1 + 4 + 6 + 4 + 1$ has no canonical cut in the middle. I would guess that it works for $(2n+1)$-orthoplexes. Somehow I was hoping that something nice happens and we can remedy the above problem by "wrapping a surface twice" around the 6 inner cells or something like that - the usual kind of magical thinking when you are not familiar with the topic..
